# Computer turned off while installing nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, drivers

1. I began installing nvidia drivers
2. The computer suddenly kicked me out of ubuntu and I was taken to that place where the screen is completely blank, and a bunch of terminal output appears. The screen didnt change for a while and I sat there waiting.
3. I pressed the power button on my computer, thinking that it had frozen or some other error had occured.
4. When I got back into ubuntu, I couldn't connect to Wifi.
5. I tried to go to Windows 11 to download wifi drivers.
6. Windows 11 gave me error 0xc000001 - Recovery: Windows failed to start

I dont know what to do. I'm not able to get Wifi on Ubuntu or get into Windows.  I've tried reinstalling ubuntu, reinstalling Windows, running the repair tool in windows, updating the bios, contacting microsoft support, etc.

What do you think happened? Is my computer just broken?

Comment: As far as Windows repair goes see https://superuser.com/questions/1068542/windows-10-fail-to-boot-with-0xc0000001-error-code where it looks like you can boot to Windows media and perform an automatic repair.  As far as your Ubuntu goes we would need more information about your hardware that will tell us what Wi-Fi chipset it has so that possibly we can point you into the right direction to get the right drivers for your system.